# Overflow x axis not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide inner nested elements within a parent wrapper, so that the wrapper can scroll horizontally to display the hidden elements. Here is a [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/mutoqupixo/edit?html,css,output).

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: thin dotted;
}
span {
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Three</span>
  <span>Four</span>
</section>
```

Comment: So whats wrong with your demo? Scroll is visible, if your items were in single line, then `.wrapper` will be scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `white-space: nowrap` to `.wrapper`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: thin dotted;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
span {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
  <span>Three</span>
  <span>Four</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Nice.  Ultimately, this is the same thing I pointed out.  The scroll bars were working, but there was no x-overflow.

Answer (score 0):

try `overflow-x: auto;` instead of `overflow-x: scroll;`